native React runtime does not include the Node standard library
i am relatively new to react native. i made some changes to my app which is built using expo managed workflow and since then the app crashes upon  compilation throw the following error.
Android Bundling failed 20210ms index.js (1632 modules)
The package at "node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/Updates.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.
 

It is worth noting that i upgraded to app to expo 51.0.17

{
  "name": "kaolo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~51.0.17",
    "expo-config": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~12.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.6",
    "expo-print": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.22.11",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
here is my package.json . 

I have tried searching on the internet to no avail i will be grateful if anyone can help me out. I have been stuck here for days
